# Google Apps Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, dns, google-apps

Hi i created a GAE application and deplyoed the application. I want to restrict the application for specific domain users. My idea is the application should display the login page of the particular domain and then the page redirects to another form in my application.
What concept should i implement here.is Userservice helps me, if so how should i direct it to my abc.domain please help me.

Help me,
Regards
Sharun

Comment: can you please elaborate it with example

Comment: i want to diplay the domain's login page in my application and it should be redirected to particular page. I tried Userservice concept but it takes to google login page but i need to display(abc.domain.com)login page

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the GAE Authentication features? I didn't understand what the other domain is for

Comment: domain which is created by me.. I created one google apps domain under which i will work on it. for eg:i name it as abc.com